# Why sometimes happend like this in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Sometimes importing the projects cause error like this : If anyone know this help me how to clear this. If you can't see the image then download from [here](http://www.ziddu.com/download/16404405/Untitled.png.html).

[image: untitled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set the build path properly to link the library.

To do so you can:

- right click on the project
- Build Path
- Configure Build Path

Comment: Shall i ask one more doubt to you?

Comment: why to me... post a thread. we will be glad to answer if possible. :)

Comment: regarding this new question I am sorry but i can't help you. I never wrote application for android...:(

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that a library used by the imported project is not found.
You should edit the build path
For the exact reason check in the log screen the markers tab

Answer (score 1):

Goto **Window->Show View->Problems**

Find the problems and fix them.